# How to convert 5 ETH worth token to another blockchain wrapped ETH without actually converting tokens to ETH

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, wrapped-tokens, cross-chain, two-way-pegged

So this is the example: we have 100 X Tokens on Etherium mainNet, which let's say has the value of 5ETH. Now I create Wrapped ETH on BSC and the Wrapped ETH price is same as ETH. (peg to ETH). Now I want to have these tokens not converted to ETH, but still the amount of the Wrapped ETH should increase accordingly to the ETH. Example:

- if Token X is worth 5ETH at one point,  we will have 5WETH in our wallets on BSC
- If Token X increases to 10ETH, we will have 10WETH in our wallets on BSC

Answer (score 0):

There two parts that have to be implemented:

- A bridge between the blockchains.
- A automated market maker.

The bridge will allow token exchange between the blockchains. The automated market maker should allow price arbitrage so the price in the secondary chain will be the same than in the primary chain.